# find the most frequently used character in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, character

this is my code to find the most frequently used character in an array. Please Debug it and also identify the error. it is working most of the time but in some cases the output is not correct. please help me with this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define size 100
int main()
{
char a[size]={0};
int i,j, k, n;
char c, e;

printf("enter size of array\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
a[n]=0;

printf("enter the characters??\n");

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    scanf(" %c", & a[i]);
  }


for(j=0; j<n; j++)
{
for(k=0; k<n; k++)
   {
     if(j==k)
       {
        continue;
       }

      else if(a[j]=a[i])
           {
              e=a[j];
           }
      else if(a[j]!=a[k])
           {
            continue;
           }
   }
}
printf("the most frequently occuring character is %c", e);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Debug it and also identify the error." No.

Comment: atleast tell where did i go wrong

Comment: What error are you seeing, and what have you done to try to debug it?

Comment: You went wrong by posting 30 lines of code and asking for us to fix it for you without being specific about what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that mostly it is displaying the required output but in some cases it is not displaying the correct output and I'm unable to find the error

Comment: You need to count the number of occurrences.

Comment: @ArhamMaroof: And what are those cases where it's wrong?  What happens in those cases, as opposed to what you expect?  This is the kind of info that goes into a decent, answerable question.  That it's not there is the biggest reason your question is being downvoted and close-voted.

Comment: @DaveRager: Code Review is for code that works, but could be improved.  SO is the right place when the code doesn't work or has known bugs.  We still need info on *how* it doesn't work, though.

Comment: @cHao yes you are right don't know what I was thinking. :-)

Comment: Did you really mean `else if(a[j]=a[i])`? That's an assignment, not a comparison.

Answer (score 2):

For fun, use at your own risk for homework:

```
int count[256];
const char input[] = "hjkshrjkhsfh2389r2jhfjkjfljsdjklf";

int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; input[i]; i++)
    {
        count[input[i]]++; 
    }

    int best = 0;
    char letter = 0;

    for(i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
        if(count[i] > best)
        {
             best = count[i];
             letter = (char)i;
        } 
    }

    printf("letter: %c, best: %d\n", letter, best); 

    return 0;
}
```

To make it a lesson, here are things that are done "bad" here that the real world would get you in trouble:

- Magic number 256 to represent all byte sizes
- my strlen check for input is very unsafe.
- doesn't handle "Huge" lists - only to 2^31 occurences allowed.
- O(strlen) + O(256) = O(n) time - might be possible to improve.
- `i` reused instead of scoped.  Var names could be more descriptive.
- No comments...

Enjoy and others are welcome to BBQ me for giving away a homework level answer like this.  Just wanted to see how fast I could put it together.